# How to add icons next to datalabels?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, chart.js-datalabels

**React ChartJS:** I'm creating a combined chart that has bars and a line. **I want to display an arrow next to the line datalabels**: if the value of the datalabel is bigger than the previous value then the arrow must point up, if it's lower must point down. I have this arrow as an SVG file available.

Me goal is to get something like this screenshot:
[image: arrow next to datalabel]

Answer (score 0):

As Datalabels plugin does not support images, in order to do this you have to code a custom plugin that will render something relative to the datalabel position.

[Here's an example in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-chartjs-icon-datalabels-zyncm7?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A72%2C18)